# Programmatically determine SharePoint Version

Tags: console-application

I am writing a console application for SharePoint. Mostly, I will be using it for both MOSS and SharePoint 2010. I have two separate functions - one for MOSS and other for SharePoint 2010.
In my Main method, I want to detect the version of sharepoint and call the funtion accordingly.

Please let me know the best way to do that.

Comment: Have you tried looking in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2205148/determine-which-edition-of-sharepoint-is-installed

Comment: Another one - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309728/how-to-determine-sharepoint-version-using-sharepoint-web-services

Comment: @NitinRastogi, I need it for console application, so this don't work

Comment: Try this - SPFarm.Local.BuildVersion;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you calling the SharePoint server API from within your console application? If so, I'm not sure this will work as you would need to reference and build your app against both the 2007 and 2010 version of the SharePoint.dlls. Visual Studio won't like that (unless you build against the 2007 version to run to the 2010 version)

Comment: You are correct! Any idea how to do it then?

Comment: Depends on what you are doing inside the console application. You might find that creating a powershell script instead of a console app is a better option.

Answer (score 4):

SPFarm.BuildVersion works with both 2007 and 2010.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spfarm.buildversion.aspx

Comment: This will not work in my situation. See answer by Paul Lucas.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check which UI the SharePoint site is having, I would recommend to use SPWeb.UIVersion property of the current site. A value of 3 means it has the SharePoint 2007 interface and a value of 4 means that it has the latest SharePoint 2010 Interface.

Comment: Just a possible workaround, if you think so. Can you have multiple console applications, the primary one just to identify the SharePoint version? I have found a post which could be helpful. http://sharing-the-experience.blogspot.com/2011/05/where-to-look-for-sharepoint-version.html